# deserializing a NOT-Standard-JSON file

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with deserializing a JSON file with VB-NET which is not in standard format [{name:value}]. Here is an example of the file:

```
["000100000000000000000000;22:03:26.991;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:04:39",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:04:11.070;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:04:39",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:05:11.252;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:10",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:13:11.920;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:15",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:13:41.924;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:46",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:14:12.249;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:14:18",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:14:42.562;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:14:44",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:15:12.729;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:15:15"]
```

The goal is to display the file in a Datagridview.

Comment: Remove first and last character, then split at ";" then sort however you want. And thats not json since it's not in json format.

Comment: @CruleD  That JSON is valid, in all RFCs. It's a simple `List<string>`.

Comment: @Jimi I could have sworn those quotations marks weren't there before. Still, he splits and then sorts. Easy.

Comment: Like Jimi said, this looks like a valid json of a string array .

Comment: @Jimi there is a useful way to deserialize the string?

Comment: @biefel Do you want help with deserialising the JSON to a List(Of String) or with using [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___), or with parsing the values from the string into strongly typed properties of a class? Does it even matter if the the values are parsed into appropriate types, or can they be left as strings?

Comment: To deserialize the JSON, you just need to specify a `List(Of String)` as destination type: `dim myList = Jsonconvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(json)`. If you then want to transform these strings in *data*, you could split the parts in 7 Columns and build a DataTable to use as the `DataGridView.DataSource`. Or just generate an `Object` array, to fill the rows of the DGV. The method of choice depends on what you want to do with the data.